# Array Reflection Basic Task

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a task to do and I managed to do the first part:

```
// create an array B that has twice as many elements as A and is 
// A forward followed by A in reverse
// if A is {3, 22, -5, 7} then we create B {3, 22, -5, 7, 7, -5, 22, 3}

// array A is declared and the size of A is 'size'
// myapproach

int B[2*size];
int i; 
for (i = size; i >-1 ; i--) {
    B[i] = A[i];
}
int j; int k;
for ( j = 2*size; j>size; i--) {
   k = size;
   k++;
   while (2*size < k) {
      B[j] = B[k];
   } 
}
```

My code works for the first part of the task ( B = {3, 22, -5, 7, } ) but I couldn't figure out the rest. Can you help?

Comment: You should only need 2 loops total and no nested loops. Also you're first loop should be from `size-1` not `size`. `A[size]` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int A[] = { 3, 22, -5, 7 };
    const size_t size = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
    int B[2 * size];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        B[2 * size - i - 1] = B[i] = A[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2 * size; i++) printf("%d ", B[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The program output is

```
3 22 -5 7 7 -5 22 3
```

As for your code then already this loop

```
        for (i = size; i >-1 ; i--) {
            B[i] = A[i];
        }
```

is wrong because there is an attempt to access the memory beyond the array `A` when the index `i` is equal to `size`.